# How do I know that ArcMap is running a tool using meters as the unit?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, units

I am not sure how to tell what units ArcMap is defaulting for with the tools it is using. For example, I am currently trying to use the line density tool to create a road density layer. I need to use this layer later on so I need to know the resolution of the output and would like to set it to a specific distance in meters. However, it seems that the tool (and other tools) always default to some other undefined measurement. I have tried changing my document to a projected coordinate system and setting the units to meters so that it actually says "meters" in the bottom right but it seems that the tools are still defaulting to something else.

Comment: What coordinate system are your data in?

Comment: Are you populating the cell size parameter of the Line Density tool? https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000000t000000 if you are not then the default is *shorter of the width or height of the output extent in the output spatial reference, divided by 250* unless you've set your cell size environment https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000001s000000. I suggest you set both cell size and snap raster environments to a single raster, it will save you lots of pain later on when your cells don't *line up*.

Comment: Most of the data is GCS North American 1983. In response to the other question, yes, I am referring to the cell size parameter in this case (although this has come up with other tools such as create fishnet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS tools work with the units of the projection system for that layer of data. So if your data's projection uses meters (e.g. UTM) any length inputs into tools will be interpreted as being in meters. Likewise if your data is in lat/long coordinates, then any inputs would be read as being in degrees.

As far as output resolution goes, @Michael Stimson made a great point in the comments about setting your output cell size, rather than accepting the default resolution. This is a second part of getting your final output resolution to be the desired size and units.